# how to add a variable at runtime to JSON-LD response

Tags: java, json-ld

I have a requirement in which I need to have an update method which can or cannot add a new variable at runtime based on the request. Below is my JSON-LD structure:

```
{
    "@type":"s:Person",
    "@context":{
        "s":"http://schema.org/",
        "description":"s:description",
        "title":"s:jobTitle",
    "knows":{
        "@id":"s:knows",
        "@type":"@id"
        }
    },
    "title":"Sys Eng",
    "description":"work on systems",
    "@id":1,
    "knows":"http://example.com/user/2345"
}
```

Below is my Java class with the variables.

```
@JsonldResource
@JsonldNamespace(name = "s", uri = "http://schema.org/")
@JsonldType("s:Person")
@JsonldLink(rel = "s:knows", name = "knows", href = "http://example.com/user/2345")
public class UserDetails {

    @JsonldId
    private int id;
    @JsonldProperty("s:jobTitle")
    private String title;
    @JsonldProperty("s:description")
    private String description;
```

As mentioned, I need to add a new variable and a url(also dynamic) value to that variable. As I understand, we cannot add a variable at runtime to a Java class, so is there any way this can be achieved? Thanks!!

Comment: Putting the property to `null` is no good?

Comment: The task that has been given states that need to have an update method, and there we might need to add a property, and the property should not be available in API.As I understand by the statement, the property needs to be added at runtime.So, cannot add in the model and initiate to null.